# Determining the image of a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Determine the image of the following function without using calculus: 
>   $$f\left(x\right)=\ \frac{x}{2\left|x\right|+1}$$

**My attempt:**

We know $\left| x \right| < 2\left| x \right| + 1$, then, $\frac{\left| x \right|}{2\left| x \right| + 1} < 1$ which implies $\left| f\left( x \right) \right| < 1$.

So $-1 < \frac{x}{2\left| x \right| + 1} < 1$.

However, the image is $-\frac{1}{2} < f\left( x \right) < \frac{1}{2}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: $|x|<|x|+1/2$

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. Let $r(f)$ be the range of $f$. You have proven $r(f)\subseteq (-1,1)$ and that is actually the case.

Comment: But that is not very accurate. All the online calculators say that it is between -1/2 and 1/2

Comment: But you actually want to prove $r(f)\subseteq (-0.5,0.5)$ and $r(f) \supseteq (-0.5,0.5)$.

Comment: To do $r(f)\subseteq (-0.5,0.5)$, use Walton's hint. And you actually need to show the reversed too, or else you are just finding upper bound and the lower bound of the range…as what you have done in the post.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comment, we also need to show that $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \subseteq r(f)$. For each $y \in (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, let

$$g(y) = \frac{y}{1-2|y|}$$
Check that $f(g(y)) = y$, so that $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \subseteq r(f)$. It follows from Walton's hint that $r(f) \subseteq (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. So $r(f) = (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

As a remark, $g \circ f= \text{Id}_\Bbb{R}$ and $f \circ g = \text{Id}_{(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) }$ and so that $f$ is actually also injective and $g$ is the inverse of $f$.